# Jquery Ajax Function Problems

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I need some help with my jquery which should complete a task in our Rails3 application. Thanks to others on here, I have a checkbox which when clicked, is supposed to mark a task's status as completed.

In my rails code, I have this;

```
<%= check_box_tag 'complete_task_1', '', false, { 'href' => completed_task_path(task.id) } %>
```

In my application.js, I started with this:

```
 $('#complete_task_1').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).data('href'),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#thing').css("color","red");
        alert ('yabadabadoo');
    }
  });
});
```

This gives me an error though - no route matches for /tasks

To test, I replaced the url with:

```
tasks/4/complete
```

Which toggled the status in the db but did not refresh on the page. I therefore have two questions:

1. What's wrong with the url / function above?
2. What can I include so that the task disappears from page without reload?

-- UPDATE --

Tried using code as per @darin-dimitrov suggestion below and I get logged out of my application... The error shown in development log is:

```
Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-16 13:27:32 +0100
  Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  SQL (143.6ms)  describe `roles_users`
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  COMMIT
Completed   in 454ms
```

Looks like it's not getting the right url still. Should I be using POST as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{ 'data-href' => completed_task_path(task.id) }
```

and then:

```
url: $(this).data('href')
```

should give the correct url (`tasks/4/complete`).

Or if you dont use the `data-` prefix you could use this:

```
url: $(this).attr('href')
```

but as `href` is not valid attribute on a checkbox the firstr solution seems better.

Comment: Thanks, tried that and strangely it logs me out of my app?! Have updated my question with the development log output

Comment: @Jenny Blunt, could you put an alert inside the `.click` handler and see what the value of `$(this).data('href')` actually is?

Comment: Can do but I don't know how! :) Am a bit new to all this! Jx

Comment: not sure if I've done this right, but I put a failure message in the handler which shows an alert which says "I must be logged in to continue". Am not sure about showing the url.

Answer (score 1):

First note very carefully that $().data() is **different** from $().attr().

Read [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/when-to-use-attr-vs-data) article for more.

On the ruby side you are probably adding an `href` attribute to the checkbox -- right?
(i am not into ruby)

Don't try to access an attribute with $().data() -- that is NOT correct.

First try to hard code the URL in the `url` property and see if it works. If yes -- then it is simply the problem that you are not able to access the `href` on the checkbox. Try `$().attr()`.

You could also use a `rel` attribute instead of `href` -- that's a standard attribute on checkboxes.
But `href` should do also.

Comment: thanks. I have actually hardcoded the url to check - this worked once and now it logs me out. Don't know why...

Comment: if it worked **once** -- then the JS side is probably working alright -- it must then be your ruby code that needs checking. Run the code through debugger and see if it reveals some glitch. Then you can ask any ruby expert about it.

Comment: @greegit, see my answer below. Mixture of a few things. Thanks again, have a good weekend :)